# Is there a shortcut way that I can set up fields of an object with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, object-literal

I have the following code:

```
obj = new Object();
obj.close = close;
obj.$form = $form;
obj.action = $form.attr('data-action')
obj.entity = $form.attr('data-entity')
obj.href = $form.attr('data-href');
obj.rownum = $link.attr('data-row');
obj.$row = $('#row_' + obj.rownum);
obj.$submitBt = $('.block-footer button:contains("Submit")');
```

Is there some way that I could combine this into one assignment with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about jQuery. It is about JavaScript. If perfunctorily: in JavaScript object is an associative array.

```
obj = {
  close: close,
  $form: $form,
  action: $form.attr('data-action'),
  entity: $form.attr('data-entity'),
  href: $form.attr('data-href'),
  rownum: $link.attr('data-row'),
  $row: $('#row_' + obj.rownum),
  $submitBt: $('.block-footer button:contains("Submit")')
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm if commas are needed after each row.